# how to display data from mysql database into two listview in one form in C#

Tags: c#, listview, visual-studio-2012

is it possible to display data from Mysql database into two Listview?
I've tried doing it but only one Listview shows the data stored in Mysql database
so I've been wondering if it is possible to do it.

**here is my code**

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection;
        string server = "localhost";
        string database = "orderingitems";
        string uid = "root";
        string password = "";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd= new MySqlCommand("Select * from itemlist ORDER BY item_name ASC",connection);
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(reader["item_name"].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(reader["item_price"].ToString());

            list_items.Items.Add(item);
        }
        MySqlCommand command= new MySqlCommand("Select * from itemcart ORDER BY itemname ASC", connection);
        MySqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (read.Read())
        {
            ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem(read["itemname"].ToString());
            item1.SubItems.Add(read["itemprice"].ToString());
            item1.SubItems.Add(read["itemquantity"].ToString());
            item1.SubItems.Add(read["itemtotal"].ToString());
            listcart.Items.Add(item1);
        }
        connection.Close();

    }
```

Comment: which list view is displaying the data ?

Comment: Can I see your code for trying to add to the second `ListView`? Right now I can only see the first one being populated.

Comment: You are massively voilating DRY principle here but aside from that - you only need one MySqlCommand and one MySqlDataReader and one while loop for your reader. Inside that while loop you can do your thing with the two list views. But you really need to start following some SOLID principles with your coding practices.

Comment: readers don't quite work the way you're trying to do it; you need to refactor

Answer (score 0):

Note: OP is in fact using two separate tables. However I would suggest making sure:

1. The table name is correct
2. The field names are correct
3. Data exists in the table

---

Look at your table fields. One is wrong. It's either item_name or itemname.

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(reader["item_name"].ToString());

ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem(read["itemname"].ToString());
```

Correctly name your table field names and that should sort your problem.

Comment: no those to are from two different table can you check again please you can see that i select two different table for two different listview

Comment: You're right. You are and I missed that. So why don't you use the field names from the table that you know works in the list view that doesn't show anything. If your data shows up twice then you know it's probably a problem with your second table.

Comment: well I've already solve it by creating two function for display an just calling it so well anyways thanks for answering.